# Find the solution to the recurrence equation, how do I do this if a variable does not cancel out in the system of equations?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

The recurrence equation is an= a n-1 + 20 a n-2. I ended up with an = A(-4)^n + B(5)^n, and my system of equations gave me -3A +6B = 3. My professor did not show us what to do in this case. Somebody, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

A second order recurrence equation usually expects two initial conditions.

Try something like

```
RSolve[{a[n]==a[n-1]+20 a[n-2],a[1]==1,a[2]==4},a[n],n]
```

and see what you get. You will probably need to use whatever initial conditions are appropriate from your problem description.